# Is Activator.CreateInstance available in DotNet 3.5?

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, activator

Do we have Activator.CreateInstance available in DotNet 3.5 ?

Comment: did you take a look on MSDN? (under supported frameworks). Best way to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes, since .NET 2.0.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3k6dfxfk%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[Yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) :-)

It's also available in .Net 4.0.